# setting Visibility of jButton of one class from another

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jbutton

I have a main class which contains some panel and some buttons, and there is one other class through which I want to set visibility of buttons in main class.

I have added one function to set visibility in main class
like:

```
// This is my main class  
public void setVisibility(boolean flag)  
{   
    mybutton.setVisible(flag);  
}

// this is class which calls the method,
my_constructor.setVisibility(false);
```

but this is not working, can anybody help?

Comment: Can you provide some more code in your example? This should work fine, even without a call to repaint() (invalidate() would actually be better!). Maybe check your threads if the EDT isn't being held up somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to repaint the panel after setting the visibility?

```
// This is my main class  
public void setVisibility(boolean flag)  
{   
    mybutton.setVisible(flag);  
    myPanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your call to the setVisibility(boolean) method on the EventDispatcherThread? (can't tell from the little code you posted).

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       setVisibility(flag);
   }
 };

EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
```

Another  minor point is you are encapsulating a call to the setVisible() method with a method named setVisibility(). If I had to maintain that code after you I would be cursing your name:-) IMHO, just make the method name the same.